# Output is shaky after exporting an edit of several clips in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, framerate

I am quite new to video editing, and I am trying to make a clip out of different source footage:

- sources made from my DSLR are at 24FPS
- sources from my video camera are at 24.97FPS
- Other sources (video clips) are at 29.97FPS

I wanted to edit those videos and to upload the result. However when I choose the "Vimeo 720p" export preset (29.97FPS), the exported final clip appears to shake from frame to frame, which is annoying.

I wonder whether that could come from the different framerates used throughout the project, and if so, how could I solve the issue?

Comment: When you re-render 24FPS to 29.97 FPS, every 5th frame will be repeated, which will make the image appear to "stutter"

Comment: @pojo-guy, that's the exact symptom! If you'd post that as an answer i'd be happy to mark it as answered :)

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, but I think they we're saying that there is a shake that happens to the video after it gets exported. It keeps happening to me and is super annoying. I read it could be unnecessarily high output settings.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your footage are shaky, because you filmed it that way? Try to use effect "Warp Stabilizer".

If it will not work, try to described in detail what you mean by "shake from frame to frame".

Comment: I'm guessing that because Premiere is dropping frames from the source in order to conform to the output FPS, there's stuttering which results in a visual 'shake'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
No, the source footage is really not shaky, it is something that is created from the editing/exporting process. What I describe as "shaky" is that when reading the exported video I have an impression of a up-down vibration of the whole picture a few pixels in extension at a rather high frequency (few Hz). Is that clearer?
@Mulvya, what I don't get is that even the part originating from a ~30FPS footage comes out as "shaky" too, and I don't see why he would drop frames for that one...?

Comment: Check interlacing - whether interlaced and field order of - source clips, project and output

Answer (score -1):

Being good at Premiere Pro, and as advised above, use Warp Stabilizer or try changing format. If problem occurs edit your question and give detail